# Bisquick waffle surface is inconsistent. Likely equipment or recipe problem?

Tags: equipment, waffle

I've been using the same waffle recipe and waffle maker for about 10 years.  Lately, my waffles have changed a bit.

- Waffle iron takes quite a bit longer to indicate done.  Previously I'd expect it  to be ready a few seconds after a 5 minute timer went off.  Now it can be closer to a minute afterward.
- Surface of waffles is no longer as uniform.  The center has often either collapsed or otherwise not stuck to the upper iron, leaving an undercooked "divot".  (But not 100% of the time.  I can still get a good surface occasionally)

[image: Waffles!]

It's a 10-year-old Black & Decker that has worked well.  The grilles have no obvious damage to the surface, but I can believe that something related to them has changed.  I wouldn't be too upset to replace it.  (Replacing the removable grilles appears to cost more than replacing the unit).  There's only a single ring-shaped heating element in each half.  So I don't think the heating is the problem.  I'd expect a consistent hot-spot or a consistent cold spot away from the center.  Neither of those seem to be happening.

My worry is that replacing would be useless because something is off with the recipe.  In my case it's just Bisquick (mainly because I never do any prep the day before, I won't have buttermilk or yeast, and it's worked great previously).  This is the only thing I use Bisquick in, and I'm concerned that a change in the product could be the issue instead. My double-batch as made:

- 576g Bisquick
- 2 eggs
- 4 Tbs vegetable oil
- 2 2/3 cup milk

Each waffle is made with a shy 1-cup batter poured into center.

While I normally try to apply a spray oil before every batch, I do occasionally forget.  When that happens, I haven't noticed it being significantly better or worse.

Anyone know if these craters are an indication of a problem with surface of the iron?

---

While it could be a lack of heat, it looks to me more like the batter in the center is not sticking or otherwise remaining in contact with the upper surface.  I'm supposing the grille is hot, but that there's an air gap to the batter.  Seems odd that it's always the center where it pulls away.

Comment: It does look like an issue with getting the heat to the middle. Are there any screws you can tighten up?

Comment: Maybe "batter poured into center" is cooling the center to much.

Comment: Could be.  It seems to me like rather than the iron not being hot enough, it's more a problem with the batter not remaining in contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the years since I posted this, the waffle recipe on boxes of Bisquick has changed.  Not sure if the product has or not.

*But*, (with that same waffle iron), I am now getting much more consistent results.

My main suspicion is that **it was the brand of spray oil I was using**.   I think that enough is left behind that even when I accidentally made a batch with no oil didn't change anything.   But after I got a different kind of spray oil, this really hasn't happened.   (The old kind was a product that used to be available at Trader Joe's, but they've long since changed it out).

Compared to the old recipe I was using, I have doubled the eggs and added more milk for a *slightly* thinner batter.   But the timing of it makes it appear that the spray oil was the more important change.